# Parsing xml string containing hyperlink

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am using DOM to parse an XML string as in the following example.  This works great except in one instance.  The document which I am trying to parse looks like this:

```
<response requestID=\"1234\">
    <expectedValue>Alarm</expectedValue>
    <recommendations>For steps on how to resolve visit <a href=\"some website\">Website</a> and use the search features for \"Alarm\"<recommendations>
    <setting>Active</setting>
<response>
```

The code I used to parse the XML is as follows:

```
try {   
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlResult));

        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nlResponse = doc.getElementsByTagName("response");

        String[] String = new String[3];  //result entries

        for (int i = 0; i < nlResponse.getLength(); i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nlResponse.item(i);
            int c1 = 0; //count for string array

            NodeList ev = e.getElementsByTagName("expectedValue");
            Element line = (Element) ev.item(0);
            String[c1] = (getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
            c1++;

            NodeList rec = e.getElementsByTagName("recommendations");
            line = (Element) rec.item(0);
            String[c1] = (getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
            c1++;

            NodeList set = e.getElementsByTagName("settings");
            line = (Element) set.item(0);
            String[c1] = (getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
            c1++;
```

I am able to parse the code and put the result into a string array (as opposed to the System.out.println()).  With the current code, my string array looks as follows:

```
String[0] = "Alarm"
String[1] = "For steps on how to resolve visit"
String[2] = "Active"
```

I would like some way of being able to read the rest of the information within "Recommendations" in order to ultimately display the hyperlink (along with other output) in a TextView. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer that without seeing your code (short of writing the while thing for you)

Comment: Sorry... I meant to post this link.  My code (for the parsing) looks basically the same.  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/ParseanXMLstringUsingDOMandaStringReader.htm

Comment: Edit your question to include the _relevant_ parts of your _actual_ code.

Comment: As a sidenote, the source looks odd to me.Usually < and > would be encoded as &lt; and &gt;. This could explain why your parser is doing dodgy stuff.

Comment: @Philippe:  This is valid XML.  Mixed content is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for my previous answer in assuming your xml was ill-formed.

I think what is happening is that your call to the getCharacterDataFromElement is only looking at the first child node for text, when it will need to look at all the child nodes and getting the href attribute as well as the text for the 2nd child node when looking at the recommendations node.

e.g. after getting the Element for recommendation

```
            String srec = "";
            NodeList nl = line.getChildNodes();
            srec += nl.item(0).getTextContent();

            Node n = nl.item(1);
            NamedNodeMap nm = n.getAttributes();
            srec += "<a href=\"" + nm.getNamedItem("href").getTextContent() +  "\">" + n.getTextContent() + "</a>";

            srec += nl.item(2).getTextContent();

            String[c1] = srec;
```

Comment: The current snippet *is* valid xml.

Comment: My mistake, I was under the impression that text couldn't appear within parent nodes alongside its child nodes.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. FWIW, when using Android, API 8 or higher must be used for getTextContent().